# Как хранить в базе данных склонение имён?

Tags: sql, postgresql

У меня есть форма, куда пользователь записывает своё ФИО в именительном падеже и родительном падежах, а также инициалы. Как я могу эффективно хранить эти данные в базе?

Comment: Укажите , пожалуйста, критерий эффективности (занимаемое базой место на диске, время выборки, простота запросов…), и порядок количества записей (до 1000, до 10.000, до 100.000 …)

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего так и нужно хранить. А каков критерий эффективности? Если занимаемое место, то можно хранить отдельно основы слов и отдельно окончания для именительного и родительного падежей: Саш, а, и.